# Substitute SelectListItem Value conditionally within Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a utility class with a member that returns an `iEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. The data is returned by the member function successfully, but I need to include optional logic to set `Value` to an index value rather than a value returned from the db.

For example, given the following (partial) database row:

```
 Key         Value        Group
-----        -----        ------
black        Black        colors
red          Red          colors
white        White        colors
blue         Blue         colors
orange       Orange       colors
```

and the following Lambda:

```
private ProgramDbContext _context = new ProgramDbContext();

// Get available options for this design parameter
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> defaultchoices = _context.Settings
    .Where(dc => dc.Group == "colors")
    .Select(dc => new SelectListItem { Text = dc.Key, Value = dc.Value })
    .ToList();
```

The above returns as expected.

```
Value        Text
-----        -----
black        Black
red          Red
white        White
blue         Blue
orange       Orange
```

But I have a need to optionally set the Value to a numbered index to return the following:

```
Value        Text
-----        -----
0            Black
1            Red
2            White
3            Blue
4            Orange
```

How do I modify the above Lambda to accomplish this? Can it be done as a conditional within the Lambda or does there need to be two Lambda expressions within a conditional `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to sometimes display value sometimes index, then you can first return them all in the query:

```
var defaultchoices = _context.Settings
    .Where(dc => dc.Group == "colors")
    .Select((dc, i) => new { Index = i, Text = dc.Key, Value = dc.Value })
    .ToList();
```

Then either in the Controller or View convert it to what you need, such as for value:

```
var selectListItems = defaultchoices.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.Key, Value = c.Value });
```

For index:

```
var selectListItems = defaultchoices.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.Key, Value = c.Index});
```

Comment: I didn't think of this at all. It gives me everything I need.